# Difference between these selectors

Tags: html, css

Is there any difference between these selectors?

`div.demo` and `div .demo`

`div#demo` and `div #demo`

Does it select the same element?

```
div.demo{some code}
div .demo{some code}
```

Comment: Of course there is – “space” is the _descendant_ selector. Read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

Comment: the provided question is different than me.

Comment: @Chapurlink — It doesn't have the same wording, but it is the same question.

Comment: @CBroe — They're called [combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) now (since they can't select anything by themselves).

Comment: I want to know how div.demo selects and div     .demo selects?

Comment: I do not understand the many downvotes. It is difficult to search for such a feature if you do not know the terms of different selectors. If you think this question can improved, leave a comment instead of silently downvoting.

Comment: It's probably because basic CSS tutorials cover this

Comment: @ w4rumy I totally agree with you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is.

`div.demo` will match a `div` with class `demo`

```
<div class="demo">
```

`div .demo` will anything with class `demo` inside any `div`:

```
<div>
  <span class="demo">
</div>
```

Same with the id selector `#`.

Answer (score 4):

```
div.demo
```

will select `div` with class `demo` whereas

```
div .demo
```

will select any **descendant** of a `div` with class `demo`. Same concept for the second case.